# Premature ending of generator in list comprehension

Tags: python, generator, list-comprehension

I'm using generators in list comprehensions, and getting some unexpected behavior with one of the generators ending early. Why does creating the generator outside of the list comprehension cause the behavior to change?

The generator I created is as follows:

```
def inc_range(a,b):
    for i in range(min(a,b), max(a,b) + 1):
        yield i
```

The first way of calling is as follows:

```
[(i,j) for i in inc_range(1,3) for j in inc_range(4,6)]
```

This gives me the following result:

```
[(1, 4), (1, 5), (1, 6), (2, 4), (2, 5), (2, 6), (3, 4), (3, 5), (3, 6)]
```

The second way of calling it is as follows:

```
a = inc_range(1,3)
b = inc_range(4,6)

[(i,j) for i in a for j in b]
```

This gives me the following:

```
[(1, 4), (1, 5), (1, 6)]
```

Experimenting around, the following two examples gave me the first result:

```
a = range(1,4)
b = range(4,7)

[(i,j) for i in a for j in b]
```

```
a = (i for i in range(1,4))
b = (i for i in range(4,7))

a = list(a)
b = list(b)

[(i,j) for i in a for j in b]
```

While the following gave me the second result again.

```
a = (i for i in range(1,4))
b = (i for i in range(4,7))

[(i,j) for i in a for j in b]
```

What rule am I violating here regarding generators? Why does it make a difference when I assign the generators to variables before using them in a list comprehension, vs. using them directly?

**ANSWERS**

Check out the following answers which helped me understand what is occurring here:

[Alex Yu](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54895520/11121902)
[mkrieger1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54895552/11121902)

Comment: unrelated - do not use `for x in ...: yield ..` - use `yield from range(min(a,b), max(a,b) + 1)`

Comment: @PatrickArtner didn't know about `yield from`, thanks for the tip.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something. Your first way and second way are different only in one thing: `j in inc_range(3,6)` vs `b = inc_range(4,6)`. Obviously you get different results. Then you make analogous operations with just `range` and get results equal to "first way" or "second way". What was the point of all this? I'm confused

Comment: @AlexYu that was a typo copying over, they're both inc_range(4,6)

Comment: @AlexYu in the second example, the first two iterators (a and b) are stopping iteration after only yielding one value, rather than yielding 3 values from each iterator.

Comment: @bbminerva Yeah. I see your edit

Comment: You couldn't possibly get the result you got in the first one because the list comprehension creates a list of 3-tuples; whereas the result you got only contains 2-tuples

Comment: @smac89 a typo from the question being simplified -- I'll fix it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get the desired result, the "inner" generator would have to be run as many times as the "outer" generator yields a value.

But, after the first run, the "inner" generator is exhausted and cannot be run again.

Adding a `print` illustrates this (simplifying the example):

```
>>> def inc(a, b):
...    for i in range(a, b):
...        print(i)
...        yield i
...
>>> a = inc(1, 4)
>>> b = inc(4, 7)
>>> [(i, j) for i in a for j in b]
1  # <-- a begins to run
4  # <-- b begins to run
5
6  # <-- b exhausted here
2  # <-- a continued, but not resulting in list item, because lacking value from b
3
[(1, 4), (1, 5), (1, 6)]
```

The reason why not storing the generators in variables works as expected is because a new "inner" generator is created for each iteration of the "outer" generator. Again, illustrated by some prints:

```
>>> def inc(a, b):
...    print('started', a, b)
...    for i in range(a, b):
...        yield i
... 
>>> [(i, j) for i in inc(1, 4) for j in inc(4, 7)]
started 1 4
started 4 7
started 4 7
started 4 7
[(1, 4), (1, 5), (1, 6), (2, 4), (2, 5), (2, 6), (3, 4), (3, 5), (3, 6)]
```

The reason why using `range` objects or lists works as expected is because they can be iterated over arbitrarily many times without being exhausted.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation!

Comment: Your point about "again" - is great. I remember now that I had similar confusion as OP many years ago and then forgot till today

Answer (score 1):

A generator is an iterable object hence when you call it outside of a list it returns the next item alone.

```
a = inc_range(1,3)
b = inc_range(4,6)
c = inc_range(7,9)

[(i,j,k) for i in a for j in b for k in c]
```

This will only yield the elements for k in c when run

Hence you need to iterate through all its objects as you have when defining it as an array.

```
[(i,j,k) for i in inc_range(1,3) for j in inc_range(3,6) for k in inc_range(7,9)]
```

This forces the generator to yield all values in each of the iterations.

Comment: I don't think I quite understand the example. All three are iterators, and should iterate until they raise a `StopIteration`. I thought the `for i in a` would keep calling `a` until a `StopIteration` is thrown, much like what occurs when I turn it into a list first.

Comment: @Alex Yu describes this well